# Executing a SQL Job only once a month and after completion of a specific job

Tags: jobs

Let me better explain. My first job executes every 15 minutes (top of the hour, 12:15, 12:30 and 12:45). It does this for every day of the week. 
I have a second job that runs at 1:30 AM on the first day of the month. This job only runs once a month.

I need to daisy chain job one with job two only on the last execution of a given month. Meaning, job one executes at 11:45 pm and executes for 3 hours, at that point I need job two to start.

Thanks in advance.
RC

Comment: Are you talking about the DBMS SQL Server? SQL is just a language.

Answer (score 1):

For SQL Server, you can specify **On success action** to go to the next step, only when the job step #1 is completed. There, use a date/time condition to execute the job#2

```
if (day(getdate()) = 1 and DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())= 1)
EXEC dbo.sp_start_job N'job#2'
```

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thanks Milena, I'm thinking of heading down this road however need some more recommendations please. My second job can only run once. My first job, step 1 runs every 15 minutes. However my second step can only run on the completion of the step 1

Comment: Try to create a time condition for a specific period. Instead of if (day(getdate()) = 1 and DATEPART(hh, GETDATE())= 1), try if (day(getdate()) = 1 and CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) > '1:01' and CONVERT(VARCHAR(8),GETDATE(),108) < '1:15'). That way, you'll have the second step executed only on the first day in a month, if the first step is completed between 1:01 and 1:15